# Open link in New tab seamlessly without interfering

Tags: browser

How can I open the js link in new tab seamlessly without interfering. I should remain on same tab without refresh it but clicked link should open in new tab ???

Comment: Your question is very vague. could you give us some more details on your issue

Comment: when I click  on link it should open in new tab but I should stay on current tab. I mean tab should not switch when click on the link.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean how to allow a user to open a link on your website in a new tab without them having to press Ctrl+Click.

This can be achieved by the following HTML:

`<a target="_blank" href="link_address_here">Link</a>`

If you are looking for functionality just to open a new tab on clicking a link when just browsing the internet without having to press Ctrl+Click it will vary between browsers:

For Chrome you can install this [Add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/click-to-tab/ebicmkkcnhdiglneianohfjapmanjoek/reviews?hl=en).
A similar [Add-on](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/open-new-tab/?display=en) is also available for Opera.
Firefox similarly has its own [Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/open-link-in-new-tab/)

Comment: No, I just want the same functionality as  Ctrl+Click but I do not want to press CTRL manually. So how can I press it using js code with click event.

Comment: Are you creating the website or are you just browsing the internet? For example are you surfing the internet and you want this function all over the internet or are you a Web Developer who wants this functionality on their page?

Comment: Yup, I am a web developer and want this functionality  on a page

Comment: then using the above HTML in as a link will provide that functionality

Comment: Definitely it will open in new tab but also what I want is that I should stay on current tab. Using above link it will redirect me on new opened tab.

Comment: There is no way to do this with pure HTML, There are dodgy, hacky ways of attempting  this with JavaScript however it is not recommended and most likely would not work with all browsers. Furthermore, Security software would probably try to circumvent this action due to it behaving like an old school popup